# socket.io and vue.js fetching data

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, sockets, vue.js

I am trying to fetching the data of vue.js using this

```
fetchData: function () {
                socket.emit('getAllSongs')
                socket.on('allSongs',function(data) {
                    this.songs = data
                });

          }
```

FetchData is called when the vue app is created

```
created: function () {
            this.fetchData();
        }
```

But when I try to call the variable **songs** outside socket.on it stills empty.

What could I do?

Comment: `this.songs` value of `this` is different in this context and is not what you are expecting, one quick workaround is to save the value of this outside the function and use it then.

Comment: How could reference to the right 'Songs' ? I tried to call a function inside socket.on to do that but it could not find the function. I am a little bit lost right now

Answer (score 3):

Try changing you `fetchData` function to this:

```
fetchData: function () {
    socket.emit('getAllSongs')
    var that = this;
    socket.on('allSongs',function(data) {
        that.songs = data
    });
}
```

The reason is the value `this` is different in the callback context and is not the component object which you expect it to be.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to bind this to the end of your function or to use ES6 arrow syntax `=>`

```
socket.on('allSongs',function(data) {
    that.songs = data
}.bind(this));

socket.on('allSongs',data => {
    that.songs = data
});
```